# Can dielectric slab be used to move an object?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

Could a dielectric slab, as in http://www.physicsbootcamp.org/Forces-on-Dielectrics.html:

[image]

be placed in a "box" together with a battery and solar panel (for example) where the slab is fixed at x=L (to give the maximum force) and be used to move the entire object? The slab would be fixed to one of the box walls and the battery would power the capacitor to constant voltage.

Probably the magnitude/direction of the force could be controlled via the voltage.

I guess the question relies if the force that is acted on the slab produces somehow an opposite force on the capacitor that "cancels" it?

Comment: Potential it would be a very efficient mechanism. What you need to do is evaluate the sort of force which might be achieved and there needs to be the introduction of a spring to return the slab back to its "off" position.

Comment: Thank you, I'm (currently) not even considering the performance, just to know if this is theoretically possible, which I believe you say it is.

Comment: Closers, what is unclear here? I guess it's because it's a question about a physical object that could be constructed on a bench rather than just stains on a whiteboard.

Comment: @JohnDoty As a closer I thought is was more of an engineering problem?

Comment: @Farcher It seems to me to be more about the physics, not about engineering detail.

Comment: If you think it should be reopened then I do not mind.  My thought was that the Physics is done in the OP's link.

Comment: I hoped my last question would be clear, in the link I provided the physics is done for the force the slab experiments. My question is if there is another force on the capacitor. All the search I performed calculates the force on the slab and I can't find a confirmation (or not) that no other force exists in this system. This is purely a physics question, I'm not asking for materials, batteries, dimensions. Just if there are other force(s) present in this system.

Answer (score 0):

In a real system, there will be other forces: things won't just float in space.

The electrostatic force on the dielectric slab is purely attractive, in the direction pulling the slab into the capacitor, unless there is dielectric hysteresis. I don't know if there's a material with enough hysteresis to reverse the force.